# Storing MySQL Table Fields in A PHP Array

Tags: php, json

I have a table in MySQL database called `location` which looks like

[image]

Now I need to store all values in a PHP array in a format which I can use the php's `json_encode()` function to export them as a JSON file which look like

```
{"markers":[
  {"Id":1, "type":shelter, "lat":55.6295639, "long":12.6392556, "lag long":"55.6295639,12.6392556" },
  {"Id":2, "type":shelter, "lat":54.6295639, "long":12.86392556, "lag long":"55.6295639,12.6392556" },
  {"Id":3, "type":shelter, "lat":56.6295639, "long":11.6392556, "lag long":"55.6295639,12.6392556" },
]}
```

Can you please let me know how I can store the data into an array called `$markers = array();`

Answer (score 0):

Most propably you need to use `iterator_to_array` method first on your collection so it would then look like: `json_encode(iterator_to_array($databaseResult));`

Answer (score -1):

```
$markers = array();
foreach($locations AS $location) {
    $markers[] = array('Id' => $location['id'], ...);
}

echo json_encode($markers);
```